# Unexpected sql operation order in Rails controller action

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqltransaction

We have an action that returns a dynamic list of user emails that are due for a monthly newsletter. The action takes an optional `mark_as_sent` parameter, which if present will update the user records to show they were sent an email today.

But even though the update operation happens *after* the users have been selected, the action always returns an empty list when `mark_as_sent` is true.

The two operations are not part of the same transaction, so I don't understand why the first one seems to be taking effect before the second?

```
  def monthly_email_list

    last_month = DateTime.current-1.month
    # Grab all users who havent received a monthly follow up email in a month or more:
    @users = User.where("monthly_email_sent < '#{last_month}' AND on_mailing_list = 't'").select("email","id") 

    if params[:mark_as_sent]
      count = User.where("monthly_email_sent < '#{last_month}'").select("email","id").update_all(:monthly_email_sent => DateTime.current)
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails lazy-loads data from first query, and executes second one immediately. Try to force the first query:

```
@users = User.where("monthly_email_sent < '#{last_month}' AND on_mailing_list = 't'").select("email","id").to_a
```

Comment: That's exactly what it was. I ended up using `User.where(...).all`, as `.all` prevents lazy loading as described [here](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface). Seems to work same as `.to_a`